# How can i set data into adapter in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want get some data from server and show it into `Recyclerview`. I can show this data, but some time not show this data and just show progressBar.
I show this data in `Log.e` and show **fastly**, but not show this data in `RecyclerView` and just show Progress.
**Please see below picture to know my mean :** 
[Click too see](https://s8.postimg.org/i58gcazg5/image.jpg)

**My Response codes:**

```
InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
Call<CountryResponse> call = api.getCountryList();

call.enqueue(new Callback<CountryResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<CountryResponse> call, Response<CountryResponse> response) {
        try {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                models.clear();
                models.addAll(response.body().getData());
                for (int i = 0; i <= models.size(); i++) {
                    Log.e("CountryInfoTAG", response.body().getData().get(i).getId() + " : " +
                            response.body().getData().get(i).getName());
                }

                countryProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mAdapter = new CountryAdapter(models, context, listener);
                countryRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<CountryResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        Toasty.error(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.failRequest),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG, true).show();
    }
});
```

**Adapter codes:**

```
public class CountryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<CountryDatum> mData;
    private Context context;
    private sendDataListener listner;

    public CountryAdapter(List<CountryDatum> mData, Context context, sendDataListener listner) {
        this.mData = mData;
        this.context = context;
        this.listner = listner;

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_country, parent, false);
        vh = new DataViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (holder instanceof DataViewHolder) {
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).countryListTxt.setText(mData.get(position).getName() + "");
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).countryListTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listner.onSendIdName(mData.get(position).getId(), mData.get(position).getName());

                    if (context instanceof RegisterActivity) {
                        ((RegisterActivity) context).dismissCountryDialog();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public void add(List<CountryDatum> models) {
        mData.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clear() {
        mData.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView countryListTxt;

        public DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            countryListTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.countryNameTxt);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix? please help me

Comment: How does this compile without casting `response.body` to an object? `response.body().getData().get(i).getName()`

Comment: Are you using Retrofit 2?

Comment: @Charlie, yes my friend, can you help me? I need this :(

Comment: So you have data & an adapter, do you have a recycler view declared in a layout of a fragment / activity already too?

Comment: @Charlie, yes my friend. I sure initialize recyclerview in activity. but not show data into recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your adapter with this:

```
public class CountryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CountryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<CountryDatum> mData;
private Context context;
private sendDataListener listner;

public CountryAdapter(List<CountryDatum> mData, Context context, sendDataListener listner) {
    this.mData = mData;
    this.context = context;
    this.listner = listner;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_country, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.countryListTxt.setText(mData.get(position).getName() + "");
        holder.countryListTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listner.onSendIdName(mData.get(position).getId(), mData.get(position).getName());

                if (context instanceof RegisterActivity) {
                    ((RegisterActivity) context).dismissCountryDialog();
                }
            }
        });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public void add(List<CountryDatum> models) {
    mData.addAll(models);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clear() {
    mData.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView countryListTxt;

    public DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        countryListTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.countryNameTxt);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What was the change to fix the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Please update your onBindView method in adapter class, do not cast like this

```
((DataViewHolder) holder)
```

Try this

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.countryListTxt.setText(mData.get(position).getName() + "");
            holder.countryListTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listner.onSendIdName(mData.get(position).getId(), 
                       mData.get(position).getName());

                    if (context instanceof RegisterActivity) {
                        ((RegisterActivity) context).dismissCountryDialog();
                    }
                }
            });

    }
```

and also print the modal after setting adapter in your success method of your Wep API callback in activity class

Answer (score 0):

The object `vh` that you return from `onCreateViewHolder` is defined as a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

```
RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
View v = // ...
vh = new DataViewHolder(v);
return vh;
```

Therefore the following statement in `onBindViewHolder` could be returning false (it would be worth checking with the debugger).

```
if (holder instanceof DataViewHolder)
```

In order to fix it, try defining your class like this:

```
public class CountryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataViewHolder> {
    // ...
}
```

From here you will also need to change a couple of methods:

```
@Override
public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_country, parent, false);
    return new DataViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.countryListTxt.setText(mData.get(position).getName() + "");
    holder.countryListTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listner.onSendIdName(mData.get(position).getId(), mData.get(position).getName());

                if (context instanceof RegisterActivity) {
                    ((RegisterActivity) context).dismissCountryDialog();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you send me full code of adapter with your codes? please my bro . I need this :(

Comment: are you here? can you help me? please my friend

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this until now. You fixed it?